# Amazon Product Advertising API wrong price return

Tags: amazon-web-services

I use the following code to get informations about amazon products:

```
 $id = "B00355GLBY";
 $base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml";
    $params = array(
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => "AWSAccessKey",
        'AssociateTag' => "AssociateTag",
        'Version' => "2011-08-01",
        'Operation' => "ItemLookup",
        'Service' => "AWSECommerceService",
        'Condition' => "All",
        'IdType' => 'ASIN',
        'ResponseGroup' => 'Offers, Images, ItemAttributes',             
        'MerchantId' => 'All',                     
        'ItemId' => $id);

    $params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());

    $url_parts = array();
    foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
        $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
    sort($url_parts);

    $url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
    $string_to_sign = "GET\necs.amazonaws.com\n/onca/xml\n" . $url_string;

    $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, "SECRET_KEY", TRUE);

    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

    $url = $base_url . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;

    $parsed_xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $original_price = $parsed_xml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->FormattedPrice;
    $original_image = $parsed_xml->Items->Item->LargeImage->URL;
    $stock = $parsed_xml->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->AvailabilityAttributes->AvailabilityType;
    $original_product_name = $parsed_xml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title;
```

My problem is that sometime I get wrong price return.
For example with this ASIN: B005Y6F4WO the price what I get is: 0.87$
I would like to receive the (main)price that is shown on center of the page. How can I make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with *sometimes*? Could you be a bit more specific please?

Comment: I mean with some items. Like these: B00BRQ3QWK B0038W0K2K B00AWNHSSM I get the lowest price, but I need the default one.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as well. Haven't found a solution yet, did you?

Comment: I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Same here! Any luck guys?

Comment: hi there, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having issues... Is the retrieved price lower than on Amazon itself, then these prices seem to be caused by the API returning the lowest price of all sellers. You could try to check on Condition=New instead of All.

I use WooZone Amazon Affiliate for Wordpress and it has these issues.